# EF Core force AsNoTracking in a static class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am looking to see if there is away to force the AsNoTracking in a static class ? I know there are other ways of doing it but, this is used all over the application. This is just basic example. SearchTest().Search()

```
    private IQueryable<SomeModel> SearchTest()
    {
        return  (from t in _dbContext.test
                     select new SomeModel()
                     {
                      a.test1
                     }).AsQueryable();
    }


    public static async Task<SomeModel> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
         return new SomeModel(){ Count=await query.CountAsync()};
    }
```

Comment: I can add asnotracking to each query. Not what do you mean?

Comment: `dbContext.test.(...).AsNoTracking()`? The fact that the class or method is static, is irrelevant.

Comment: @CodeCaster: You can add that in the SearchTest but in the Search<T>  is not available. My example is bad... let me update it !

Comment: In this example I do not see the benefit even of using AsNoTracking as the only thing every being done on the data store is a Count and this would not be tracked in the DbContext as no entities are returned. Even if it returned the projection from `SearchTest` the use of SomeModel is a projection and this also would not be tracked because it is not the mapped entity being returned.

Comment: Also if you do want to use `AsNoTracking` it does not matter where you apply it as long as it is applied to some instance where the type implements IQueryable or IQueryable<T>. See also [DbExtensions.AsNoTracking Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbextensions.asnotracking?view=entity-framework-5.0.0).

Comment: @Igor: yes you are right!! I do not need that! Solved. Thanks